# NAudio API and the output device

Tags: audio, naudio, wasapi, naudio-framework

My question is simple,
When choosing which Api to use Wasapi or Asio, does the choosing process depends on the output device if it supports Wasapi , Asio etc so do we need to have info about the output devices that we will use, or these api are standard for all the possible output devices

I'm trying to get some info about the drivers and API) used in NAudio,